# crash iOS7 when swaping cameras using setCameraDevice

Tags: ios, ios7, crash, camera

My application used to work just fine on iOS 6.2. Since we updated to iOS7 when we swap the cameras (something that we already did earlier) it crashes.

This is my code:

```
-(void) swapCameras
{
    if (self.cameraDevice == UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear)
    {
        [self setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];
    }
    else 
    {
        [self setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear];
    }
}
```

If i start the camera with UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront it works perfectly. But if I start with UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear or try to change it while running it crashes.

Is this crash a bug on iOS 7? Did someone else have this crash?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone faces the same problem, I found the solution by updating the iOS version.
This bug happened when I was using the iOS 7.0.0. I updated it to iOS 7.0.4 and it doesn't crash anymore. This bug probably has been fixed by apple in any of the updates between these two versions.

Furthermore, as this updates are not mandatory and some users might not have updated to the latest iOS version, I had to make a trick in the code to get the current iOS version and avoid crashing. I did it by using the following macros:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]        systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]   systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

Then, I use it in the code like this:

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0") && SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0.4"))
{
    // Do your work to avoid crash
}
```